# Java-8 Optional prevent if statement

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Is there a better way of doing this:

```
DateTime firstRecordingDate = null;
if (firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium.isPresent()) {
    firstRecordingDate = firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium.get().getStartRecord();
}
DateTime lastRecordingDate = null;
if (firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium.isPresent()) {
    lastRecordingDate = firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium.get().getStartRecord();
}
```

Comment: For the record it seems you are assigning the same value to both variables. Probably a bug there…

Answer (score 3):

If you change the type of your `DateTime` variables to `Optional<DateTime>`, you can avoid the if statement using `map` :

```
Optional<DateTime> firstRecordingDate = firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium.map(ClassName::getStartRecord);
```

Where "ClassName" should be replaced with the type of `firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want it to stay with a default value (`null`) if no value is present, you can use the [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) methods:

```
DateTime firstRecordingDate = firstScheduleRecordWeekCompendium
    .map(YourClass::getStartRecord)
    .orElse(null);
```